# Jquery appendto specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to pass in an ID and append an element into a specific div, the current way isn't working correctly. If I was to take of the `.closest('slide_holder')` it would correctly append the `ul class='gallery'` to the bottom of the Tuesday div.

I would like the new div to be inside of slide_holder.

```
$( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" 
 ).appendTo($('#'+$droppableId).closest('.slide_holder'));
```

---

### HTML STRUCTURE

```
<div id='Tuesday'>
    <div class='slide_holder'></div>
</div>  
  <div id='Wednesday'>
<div class='slide_holder'> </div>
</div>
```

**droppableId defines what day of the week it is monday,tuesday,ect..**

```
var $droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
```

### function call

```
deleteImage($droppableId, ui.draggable);
$item = $item.clone()

$item.fadeIn(function () {

   var $list = $("ul", $droppableId).length 
       ? $("ul", $droppableId) 
       : $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($('#' + $droppableId));
   ....
```

Comment: where do you want the new div? inside the Tuesday div or inside slide_holder?

Comment: @darshanags inside of slide holder

Comment: What is `$droppableId`? I'm pretty sure you mess things there, it ain't `string` right?

Comment: Then let me tell you that you can't concatenate string to a jQuery object and get decent selector

Comment: Is $droppableId representing `<div id='Tuesday'>`?

Comment: @kidwon yes it represents whatever day of the week the user clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
OK I see what your goal is now.
You want to append the list to the **day div's** `.slide_holder` child

Do this

```
var droppable = $(this);
$('.slide_holder',droppable).append('<ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset"/>');
```

Comment: $droppableId is actually a Jquery object so I cannot do  `var closest = $droppableId.closest('.slide_holder')`

Comment: is `$droppableId` a DOM node? In what context you're using it.
Show me the code where you define `$droppableId` as `$(this)`

Comment: sorry I should of defined the question better, i've edited in the droppableid part.

Comment: I see if you show me now the structure of the HTML markup regarding what is `$droppableId` and where `<div class='slide_holder'> </div>` stands to it we'll solve the issue.

Comment: in this case $this is referring to li.item ui-draggable and not the name of the div(friday, saturday)

Comment: thanks for all your help works perfectly now i used this line: `$('.slide_holder','#'+$droppableId).append('<ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset"/>');`

Comment: Ok, glad it worked out somehow. You should really read about jQuery selectors and DOM traversing. One day effort will save you a lot of trouble, BR.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo(".slide_holder");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/wsTYL/

Comment: That would not work in my case $droppableId is a reference to $(this) and I have many divs on the page that have class of slide_holder it will appendTo all of them.

Comment: Can you include your code which has $droppableId? Need more context to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($('#' + $droppableId + ' .slide-holder'));
```

If I understand it correctly, you want to add the new element to .slide-holder but only in the $droppableId div.

**Edit:** It also sounds like there may be a scope issue with the variable $droppableId. I'd check to make sure the fadeOut callback has access to the new value, which I assume is being set in the click handler.

Comment: that is correct, and that code should work, but nothing gets added in the slide_holder div.

Comment: Where is the $droppableId being set to $(this) ? is `$(this)` pointing to the #Tuesday div?